# Java CA keystore

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to use crawler4j to reach several sites. Each https interaction starts with TLS handshake. However, I faced that it doesn't work the same on every machine. Some urls are not opened due to an untrusted certificate. I've checked, that I am using same security level on each machine.

My first guess was to check java -version, so that certificates would differ. I've installed same openJDK version of java on my server (centOS) and virtual machine (ubuntu) and by executing command `keytool -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -list` in the `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security` I see that I have 174 CA on Ubuntu,  93 on centOS. On my PC I am running same Hotspot java version and there are 104 CA.

My goal is to have the same predictable situation on each machine as I don't want to add certificates manually.

Please, clarify for me, how trustable CA relates to the running environment, java version etc?

Comment: OpenJDK, especially on Linux, usually uses (symlinks to) a truststore file provided by a different package which is separate from the Java package(s) and independent of it(them). On my elderly CentOS 6 that is `/etc/pki/java/cacerts` and is provided by `ca-certificates` using content from Mozilla. I don't know if Ubuntu uses the same content, or on the same schedule. Check if your JRE/lib/security/cacerts is a symlink, if so to where, and provided by what.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 so as I understood it could depend on many things :) what I've found on ubuntu "702874      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           27 лип 28 05:31 ./cacerts -> /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
", so it's a link to another java dir and in that dir it's not a link. So, still I am a little bit confused

Comment: The fact the directory is named /etc/ssl/certs/java doesn't mean it has to come from a java package. On Ubuntu use `dpkg-query --search` (or `-S`) to find out where it came from.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks!